# FileBaseName and a dot in the folder name

Tags: files-and-directories

```
FileBaseName["F:\\2016-02-23\\11.5_mm_fan_off_pumps_off_1500_hz_3793_\
images_2048_1472_pixels_20160223_1649_time_part"]
```

should give the base folder name:

```
"11.5_mm_fan_off_pumps_off_1500_hz_3793_images_2048_1472_pixels_20160223_1649_time_part"
```

but due to the dot after 11 the result is:

```
"11"
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: if that's a directory: `FileNameTake[path, -1]`

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `FileNameTake`, not `FileBaseName`.  `FileBaseName` does what it's supposed to here: it removes the extension, i.e. everything after the last dot.  Note that directories can have extensions too, see e.g. `.app` on OS X.

Comment: @Kuba Actually the `-1` is not needed.  It always takes the last element of the path, whether that is a directory or not.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't know why I wasn't aware of that, thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of [`FileBaseName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileBaseName.html) is not to take the last element of the path.  It's purpose is to remove the file extension, i.e. everything after the last dot in the name.  Directories can have extensions too, see e.g. `.app` on OS X.  In your example `FileBaseName` is working correctly and doing what it should.

If you want to take the last element of the path, use [`FileNameTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameTake.html).